# Isometries of Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be Riemannian manifold. Where I can find the *proof* of the following fact:

> the group of isometries of $M$ is finite dimensional Lie group.

Additional question:

> what is known about the dimension of this Lie group, does it depends from the choice of metric?

Comment: This help? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1883659/relationship-between-dimension-of-a-manifold-m-and-dimension-of-the-lie-group-g

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is called "the Myers-Steenrod theorem" and you can find it right at the beginning of chapter II (page 39) in [Transformation Groups in Differential Geometry](https://books.google.com/books?id=txdtCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA39) by Shoshichi Kobayashi. See also the references therein.

Answer (score 7):

See Kobayashi Nomizu Foundations of differential geometry Vol I theorem 3.4 p.239.