# When is isometry space of compact metric space a manifold?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, manifolds, isometry

Supposse we have a compact metric space $(X, d)$. Let $(\text{Iso}(X, d), D)$ be a metric space of all isometries $f : X \rightarrow X$ with a metric $D$ defined with:
$$D(f, g) = \text{sup}\{d(f(x), g(x)) \mid x \in X\}.$$

Im interested in the following question. When is this space $(\text{Iso}(X, d), D)$ a manifold (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold)?
In particular, what are some conditions metric space $X$ can satisfy so we can conclude $\text{Iso}(X, d)$ is a manifold?

I was able to find this post [Isometries of Riemannian manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2077385/isometries-of-riemannian-manifold?rq=1). Here it says that if $X$ is a Riemannian manifold than group of isometries is a Lie group which implies it is a manifold. Altough Im not sure that this implies space of isometries with metric $D$ defined above is a manifold.

Comment: What type of manifold? Topological one? With second-countability and Hausdorff assumptions?

Comment: Yes. But even if there are some conditions that only imply that the space is localy euclid I would be happy. It is Hausdorff beacuse it is a metric space.

Comment: @Goki While not familiar with the linked theorem about isometries of Riemannian manifolds, I would presume that in the linked post they are giving the isometry group the topology of uniform convergence, which is indeed the same topology as given by your metric $D$.

Comment: For the last paragraph, you have to assume that $X$ is connected. Are you familiar with the literature on topological transformation groups, where one of the key agenda items is to prove that certain locally compact groups are Lie groups?

Comment: Im not familiar with that. I will look into it.

Comment: Note that for a lot of spaces your distance will not define a metric, in particular any isometry that has a fix point somewhere will have distance zero to the identity isometry. So I would suspect that this will only be a metric space in some very specific examples.

Comment: This is always a metric, for isometry to have distance zero to identity it has to have all points fixed. That follows from definition of D.

Comment: I read inf instead of sup, my mistake

Answer (score 6):

**Theorem.** (Melleray) Let $G$ be a compact metrizable group, then there is a compact metric space $K$ such that $G$ is homeomorphic to $\text{Iso}(K)\subseteq K^K$ with product topology.

Reference: "Compact metrizable groups are isometry groups of compact metric spaces." by J. Melleray

Note that on $\text{Iso}(K)$ uniform and product topology coincide since its compact in uniform topology, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398511/compact-metric-space-group-operatornameisox-d-is-also-compact). Indeed, the map $(\text{Iso}(K), \tau_u)\to (\text{Iso}(K), \tau_p)$ where $\tau_u$ is uniform topology and $\tau_p$ is product topology is a map from compact to Hausdorff space, so a homeomorphism, hence $\tau_u = \tau_p$.

In particular by taking $G = \{0, 1\}^{\aleph_0}$ to be the Cantor space with operation induced from $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, we obtain that group of isometries can be quite different from a manifold.

The Hilbert-Smith conjecture implies that if $K$ is a connected manifold, then $\text{Iso}(K)$ is a Lie group. See [this post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/13/the-hilbert-smith-conjecture/) by Terence Tao. The conjecture is known for Riemannian manifolds, and for topological manifolds of dimensions $\leq 3$, so that when $K$ has one of those properties then $\text{Iso}(K)$ is a Lie group.

Comment: Thank you, i didnt know about this conjecture and cases when its solved.